# Android Studio Gradle editor runs very slow

Tags: android-studio, gradle

The Gradle editor of my Android Studio (1.2.1.1) is painfully slow.
Every time I type a few characters it freezes for a few moments.
Under *Preferencs->Editor->Inspections* I already deactivated everything in the gradle section in the hope that this would speed it up again.

My colleague has the same issue, we're working with AS+Gradle for about a week now.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but no: I don't have any news on this, it's still very annoying and I'm editing my gradle code outside of Android Studio by now.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but any news? Same problem with AS 3.0 in MacOS HighSierra... under Windows and Ubuntu works fine but in my MacBook is a torture

Comment: mine freezes as well. Very frequently, after editing gradle script for like 10s or more